# CREATE EXTENSION postgis fails with /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, postgis

Problem:

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
LOG:  statement: CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/rtpostgis-2.3.so": /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name`
```

What I've done:

- Added Postgres official PPA - `http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg/main`
- Installed Postgis - `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.3`
- I've also uninstalled `libgdal` and it's dependencies (`sudo apt-get remove --purge libgdal1i`) and then reinstalled `postgis` as above. Still same error.
- I installed clean Ubuntu in a VirtualBox and there it installed and worked ok.

Versions:

- Ubuntu - Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- Postgres - 9.5.9-1.pgdg16.04+1
- Postgis - 2.3.3+dfsg-1.pgdg16.04+1
- Libgdal - 1.11.3+dfsg-3build2 (libgdal1i)

I'm all out if ideas how to debug this further.

Answer (score 3):

OK, finally solved the problem.

**Root cause**

Postgres did not have access to `libsqlite3.so`.

**Debugging**

Error refers to `libgdal.so.1` having problems and is linked against `sqlite3`, so checked the dependencies:

```
  ~ ldd /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1 | grep "sql"
 libmysqlclient.so.20 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.20 (0x00007fc80cd65000)
 libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007fc80825e000)
```

Interesting part is that all dependencies are from `/usr/lib/...`, but `libsqlite3.so.0` is from `/usr/local/lib`. So it makes one wonder if maybe Postgres does not have access to `/usr/local/lib` and causing problems?

As it seems, officially `libsqlite` should not be installed in `/usr/local/lib`, but `/usr/lib` where it actually already existed. Removed the `/usr/local/lib` version and reinstalled the whole postgis package and it worked.

Comment: After I removed /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0 file it all worked, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Remove /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.* file, solve the problem